# Android Studio Layout Editor Error?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

After the updation of latest API 22.0.1 i couldn't view layouts other than the above error.what went wrong. Any one please help me?

Comment: Did you sync the Gradle or not.

Comment: Synched,cleaned ,rebuild and even restarted the studio..#yugesh

Comment: are you using any custom view

Comment: no #Vishwajit Palankar

Comment: @Stella Currently Layout editor in which API level.If it is in above 20 change it to 19 check it.

Comment: I set API 22 in Layout editor#Yugesh

Comment: @Stella change it to API 19 Check it and say.

Comment: It's working now.but haven't getting the expected view #yugesh

Comment: @Yugesh .why changing into API19 ?

Comment: @Stella So the problem in your style file.Till API 19 have separate theme from API 21 android use Material Theme.Why ask you change means, for checking purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Layout Editor Theme

> AppTheme to Theme.Material

and give a try.

I got the same error while switch to Material Design with API 22.0.1.it has been given same error.the changes above i made helped me to fix it.